# When I save a PSD, have it save a PNG w/ a new folder

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Could I do this? For example, if I was making a new logo, I would save the psd, it'd create a new folder called Avatar, and in that it would save the psd and the PNG.

Would that be possible?

Comment: Welcome Victory! :) You want to do this by one click? If yes, that's possible via scripting. The documentation can be found here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html

Comment: There is a sample script: `Save extra jpg.jsx`. I think it's a bit unnecessarily complicated script, but could guide you to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Photoshop CC June 2014 You can get benefit using Extract assets from layers by naming folder group .png this will ensure saving a copy of all the layers and it's sun as assets.

what I mean: you can save your PSD normally while the layers of your logo grouped in a folder layer named XXXX.PNG so you may save PSD normally in the same time you will export all group layers under a specific folder or individual layers as flatten PNG file.

please see this new feature [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html)

[image: Image asset names are generated from layer names/layer group names]

[image: Rename the appropriate layers/layer groups]

Comment: The question is about *automatically* saving a PNG snapshot of the document each time it's saved, but this answer is about saving individual assets on demand via File > Generate

Comment: why don't you answer the main question instead of critic my answer?? what I said he might "get benefit using Extract assets from layers". if you understand what I mean - and sure you don't - he can save his PSD normally while the layers of his logo grouped in a folder layer named XXXX.PNG so he may save PSD normally in the same time he will export all group layers under a specific folder or individual layers as flatten PNG file.

Comment: On reflection,  I agree this is a constructive answer. But perhaps you could refine it a bit? Can't change vote unless it's edited.

Comment: I have just edit my answer.